# windows 10 file upload and permissions php

Tags: php, windows, file, permissions, ownership

I'm having trouble moving uploaded files, the problem seems to be a permissions problem, any help would be much appreciated. I'm using windows 10 and I've change my temp folder in php.ini to a custom folder in xampp directory and when I check this temp folder the file isn't there either, so it seems that it isn't even being uploaded to them temp. Please help.

```
class PortfolioItem extends DataBaseCommonObj{

protected static $table_name = 'portfolio_item';
protected static $db_fields = array('id','filename','mimetype','size','caption','job_id');

public $id;
public $filename;
public $mimetype;
public $size;
public $caption;
public $job_id;


private $temp_path;
protected $upload_dir="_portfolio-items";
public $errors=array();

protected $upload_errors = array(
  // http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
  UPLOAD_ERR_OK                 => "No errors.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL        => "Partial upload.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE        => "No file.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "No temporary directory.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Can't write to disk.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => "File upload stopped by extension."
);

public function attach_file($file){
  global $session;
  if(!$file || empty($file) || !is_array($file)){
    $this->errors[] = 'no file was uploaded';
    return false;
  }elseif ($file['error'] != 0) {
    $this->errors[]=$this->upload_errors[$file['error']];
    return false;
  }else {
    $this->filename = basename($file['name']);
    $this->temp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
    $this->mimetype = $file['type'];
    $this->size = $file['size'];

    if(isset($session->message) && $session->message !== ''){
      $current_job = Job::find_by_id(intval($session->message));
      $this->job_id = $current_job->id;
    }
    return true;
  }
}


defined('DS')?null:define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT')?null:define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'mp_creations');
defined('INC_PATH')?null:define('INC_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
defined('PUB_PATH')?null:define('PUB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'public');


public function save(){
  if(isset($this->id)){
    $this->update();
  }else{
    if(!empty($this->errors)){
      return false;
    }

    if(empty($this->filename) || empty($this->temp_path)){
      $this->errors[] = 'file path not available';
      return false;
    }

    $target_path = PUB_PATH.DS.$this->upload_dir.DS.$this->filename;

    if(file_exists($target_path)){
      $this->errors[] = "the file {$this->filename} already exists";
      return false;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path,$target_path)){
      if($this->create()){
        unset($this->temp_path);
        return true;
      }
    }else {
      $this->errors[]='The file upload failed, possibly due to permission issues';
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide a code please. Without it it's just a magic

Comment: As far as i know temp files should remove on request end. you can set a sleep() after move_uploaded_file and check file in temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
```

Comment: cool but it hasn't been moved because its not in the target folder

Comment: When your $this->temp_path is set, give us that piece of code

Comment: edit to show setting temp path, its coming from the $_FILES in a post request

Comment: Any help here would be great guys. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to have been my methods and not anything to do with permissions. I was was using values stored in the session to pass to the move_uploaded_file() function, once I did it directly from the POST request it worked fine. Is it that the move_uploaded_file() needs to be called from a POST request? Anybody care to shed some light on this, please do as I'd love to learn what happening behind the scenes.